# How to convert all object type values in a dataframe to int

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, int

Anyone know how to convert all column values in dataframe to int?

lets say i have a dataframe containing

```
  A B C 

  1 2 1

  3 2 1

  1 4 5
```

dtypes is object how do i convert it to int or numeric

Comment: You can use pandas module pd.to_numeric(df) for converting object into numeric values.['https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html'](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html)

Comment: `df = df.astype(int)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use pandas astype() function, pandas to_numeric may also give you the behaviour you want

```
a = pd.DataFrame({"A":["1",2,3], "B":[2,"2",4], "C":[1.0,1.0,5.0]})
a.dtypes

Out[8]: 
A     object
B     object
C    float64
dtype: object

b = a.astype(int)
b.dtypes
Out[10]: 
A    int32
B    int32
C    int32
dtype: object

b
Out[11]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  2  1
1  2  2  1
2  3  4  5
```